# SharePoint React SPFX Issue with rest call for date-picker (MS Fluent UI) insertion to SPO list

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx, rest

I have been trying to insert the date field value using REST API along with some other data which would be inserted into several columns in a SPO list. The data will get inserted appropriately without any hassle by removing the date value. but with the date value the query is failing to insert the record into the SPO list. Kindly help me out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pnp js.

My test code:

*ReactFluent.tsx*

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './ReactFluent.module.scss';
import { IReactFluentProps } from './IReactFluentProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { Web, List, ItemAddResult } from 'sp-pnp-js';
import { DatePicker, DayOfWeek, IDatePickerStrings } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DatePicker';
import { mergeStyleSets } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Styling';
import { DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
const DayPickerStrings: IDatePickerStrings = {
  months: [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
  ],

  shortMonths: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],

  days: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],

  shortDays: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],

  goToToday: 'Go to today',
  prevMonthAriaLabel: 'Go to previous month',
  nextMonthAriaLabel: 'Go to next month',
  prevYearAriaLabel: 'Go to previous year',
  nextYearAriaLabel: 'Go to next year',
  closeButtonAriaLabel: 'Close date picker',

  isRequiredErrorMessage: 'Start date is required.',

  invalidInputErrorMessage: 'Invalid date format.',
};
const controlClass = mergeStyleSets({
  control: {
    margin: '0 0 15px 0',
    maxWidth: '300px',
  },
});

const firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
const desc = 'This field is required. One of the support input formats is year dash month dash day.';
export default class ReactFluent extends React.Component<IReactFluentProps,any> {
  constructor(props:IReactFluentProps,any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datePickerValue:String
    };
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactFluentProps> {
    const onSelectDate = (date: Date | null | undefined): void => {
      //console.log(date)
      this.setState({
        datePickerValue:date
      });
    };
    const onClick = (): void => {
      var date= this.state.datePickerValue;
      this._addItem(date);
    };
    return (
      <div className={ styles.reactFluent }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
              <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" className={ styles.button }>
                <span className={ styles.label }>Learn more</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <DatePicker
          className={controlClass.control}
          label="Start date"
          isRequired={false}
          allowTextInput={true}
          ariaLabel={desc}
          firstDayOfWeek={firstDayOfWeek}
          strings={DayPickerStrings}

          onSelectDate={onSelectDate}
        />
         <DefaultButton onClick={onClick} text="add" />
      </div>

    );
  }

  private _addItem(date):void
  {    
    console.log(date);
    let web = new Web(this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);  

      web.lists.getByTitle('test3').items.add({
        Title:'testTitle',
        date:date
      }).then((response)=>{console.log(response);});
  }
}
```

*IReactFluentProps.ts*

```
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
export interface IReactFluentProps {
  description: string;
  context:WebPartContext;//you need to update the props at React.createElement
}
```

Test result:
[image]